# How to setup ssh over USB on an embedded linux device?

Tags: ssh, embedded, serial-port, ppp, pppd

I have an embedded linux device with an ARM processor. I am connecting to it over a USB port using minicom. What should I do to "ssh" into the device through the USB connection?

I want to setup something like the following setup for beagle bone:

https://learn.adafruit.com/ssh-to-beaglebone-black-over-usb/overview

**Edit:** My device is *not* a beagle bone. The above link is provided as an example of what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: That looks like a cool project! Have you determined what the IP address is for it?

Comment: the device has no ethernet ports only the USB port through which I can connect through USB. At the moment, it only has the "lo" interface. I think usb ethernet would be the first thing to setup... not sure.

Comment: Well I would assume you need to check with the manufacturer and see if the embedded device comes with a wifi adaptor or some kind of means of connecting to the internet. As of right now, the only thing I can think of is mounting the device and simply navigating to the directories when mounted but this is not SSH..

Comment: The beagle bone can use ssh over USB (the link I have given) so it must be possible with this device too... but dont know how to do it... yet :)

Comment: Can you mount it and type `ifconfig -a | less`? This may provide you with the device's IP

Comment: you mean in the embedded device or on the host machine?

Comment: Try both out... I am not 100% sure that the host would capture the IP on the device.

Comment: I will try both out...

Comment: Did you read the tutorial you linked to?  A. The BeagleBoard OS is already configured and B. you need to install drivers on your remote system.  [Installing Drivers (Linux)](https://learn.adafruit.com/ssh-to-beaglebone-black-over-usb/installing-drivers-linux).  You'll have to find out what's done in their OS to support this

Comment: What they have done to the BeagleBoard OS is exactly what I am trying to find out. I seem to be looping on the terms ppp,SLIP and usb-gadgets..